# Remove row from database and directory on disk in one transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting files and corresponding entries from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739444/deleting-files-and-corresponding-entries-from-database)

I'm writing an ASP.NET application. I have a row in a database with physical path to a folder on disk. I want to delete the row and remove the directory in one transaction. I.e. make sure both are deleted or both are not.

I'm using Entity Framework to communicate with the database.

The folder to be removed contains images, which may be viewed by a web-site user. I'm afraid I could try to delete the folder at the moment an image is transferred to a user by IIS.

Comment: @Rawling: Not a dupe.  The other is looking for best practices and none of the answers apply to the requirements on this question.

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to use [Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx), if your server is Windows 2008 R2 or 2012 it will work because the Transaction will be over SQL and [NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363764%28VS.85%29.aspx). Make sure the Distributed Transaction Coordinator windows service is in running state.

Comment: That's look like exactly what I need, thanks! However, it doesn't seem very simple at a first glance, so I need to learn manuals for a while.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft claims Transactional NTFS may be deprecated in future versions of Windows and they do not recommend using it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690(v=vs.85).aspx They suggest SQL Filestreams as an alternative, I'm digging into it right now.

Comment: If you want to use SQL filestreams you should make some tests first, keep in mind that SQL Server is slower then NTFS, you'll notice a big difference when you load images from disk vs SQL. The SQL filestream performance reaches its best on large BLOB values over 1Mb.