# entity framework: own ondelete action

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

When any record deletes from some table (let us call it STORAGE_INFO) additional data from disk must be deleted.Could anyone provide a sample (if it possible yet) how to specify own DELETE action? Something like this:

```
      DBSet<STORAGE_INFFO>.ONDELETE+= CUSTOM_FUNCTION

      CUSTOM_FUNCTION()
      {
          BASE.DELETE();
          DELETE_DISK_CONTENT();
      }
```

Comment: Beware that you're in an transactional snake pit here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13034025/861716. Is Sql Server's [filestream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) a viable alternative for you?

Comment: I have a cascade deleting, so transactional scope is not for me.what about filestream this is good approach but there is not much articles on this theme (code-first + filestream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're looking for the [`ObjectContext.SavingChanges` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx)

If you iterate the result of calling the `context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted)` method using the whole overload, you'll be able to detect which entities were deleted when the `ObjectContext`saved some changes.

Check the sample code in the MSDN article (it's a good sample of how to achieve your goal!):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx

#### The original poster said:

> this is pretty.But where can I find this event in DBContext class?

Upcast the `DbContext` to `IObjectContextAdapter`:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += ...
```

Comment: this is pretty.But where can I find this event in DBContext class?

Comment: thanks,@Matías Fidemraizer! I think this will be very usefull post.